# Echo in update query

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me, in  this query how to do the echo if the quantity is more than stock?

```
$updatequery =
    "UPDATE products SET
        stock =
            CASE WHEN stock >= '$quantity' THEN
                (stock-'$quantity')
            ELSE
                stock
            END
    WHERE product = '$product' " ;
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work!

```
if (!$updatequery) {
    echo " We are sorry! The available stock of selected product ($stock units) in not enough ";
} else {
    echo "Hello $username! You ordered $product with quantity: $stock succesfully";
}
```

Comment: what is your problem now?

Comment: Make a select first, then an update and make sure that it is a transaction

Comment: `$updatequery` is just a string, not the result of executing SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$updatequery = "
    UPDATE `products`
    SET `stock` = `stock` - ".intval($quantity)."
    WHERE `product` = '".appropriate_escaping_function($product)."'
      AND `stock` >= ".intval($quantity)."
";
```

Then, check the `affected_rows` function (can't tell you exactly what function without knowing what library you're using, but a quick search should find it). If it's zero, then either the product wasn't found (which you should already know before even trying to update) or it failed the `stock >= quantity` check.

Comment: This is a good hint on proper escaping user inputs, but this answer misses the point of the question above: One need to send such a query to a DBMS. Thus, this would be better suited as a comment…

Comment: @feeela Erm, no, the question is about how to show a message when the stock is insufficient.

Comment: And where is that number stored/calculated from? Right, you got it.

Comment: @feeela The number is calculated in the query itself - if this query fails to update the row, then the stock is insufficient.

Comment: There is no UPDATE, because the query is not executed anywhere. There only is a string and a string does not compute anything.

Comment: @feeela "check the `affected_rows` function" implies that you need to execute it - that's kind of what the docs should tell you, given we don't know OP's choice of interface.

Comment: OK; than this was just too implicit… I didn't mentioned that – maybe you should state that explicitly.